# PyQt: How to position QToolTip over widget?

Tags: python, pyqt

When I click "Button1" (see screenshot below) the tooltip appears over "Button2" and not over "Button1" as I wanted:

[image]

---

**t.py**

```
import logging
import sys
# from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QToolTip, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app: QApplication):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app
        self.resize(330, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("Button1")
        layout.addWidget(button1)
        def button1_clicked() -> None:
            self.button_clicked(button1, "Button1")
        button1.clicked.connect(button1_clicked)
        button2 = QPushButton("Button2")
        layout.addWidget(button2)
        def button2_clicked() -> None:
            self.button_clicked(button2, "Button2")
        button2.clicked.connect(button2_clicked)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def button_clicked(self, button: QPushButton, txt: str) -> None:
        point = button.mapToGlobal(button.pos())
        size = button.size()
        logging.info(f"{txt} pos: {point}")
        logging.info(f"{txt} size: {size}")
        QToolTip.showText(point, txt, msecShowTime=4000)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(app)
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why does this happen? How to fix it?

Comment: The `pos` of a widget is always relative to its parent. Change to `button.mapToGlobal(QPoint())`.

Comment: did you check what you have in `button.pos()`? Maybe you need `point = button.pos()`?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks! Yes computing button pos relative to parent QMainWindow works: `point = self.mapToGlobal(button.pos())`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Be careful in doing that: as said, `pos()` is always relative to the parent, and in your case that is *not* the window, but the central widget. Right now it works because your main window has no further widgets, so the coordinate reference of the central widgets is probably the same (or close to that) of the window, but it would be invalid again in case you used a menubar, dockwidgets or toolbars. Just add `self.menuBar().addMenu('test')` somewhere in the `__init__` and you'll see. For this specific case, the correct call would be `self.centralWidget().mapToGlobal(button.pos())`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland But that may be wrong again in case you actually added the button to an inner container, like a group box or even a scroll area, placed *within* the central widget. Unless you're *extremely* sure about the relationships between the involved widgets, if you need global coordinates you should always query `mapToGlobal` of the actual widget. That's why `button.mapToGlobal(QPoint())` is the most correct call: by using `QPoint()` you're querying the function with the origin point of the widget (`0, 0`, its top left corner), resulting in the real global position, no matter the parent.

Comment: @Hakon, why not answer your own question?